# JAXB SCD path for element with inheritance

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm trying to do a simple rename of a generated property from the following schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="http://usermanagement"
           targetNamespace="http://usermanagement">

    <!-- definitions of complexTypes RoleRef and OrganizationRef omitted -->
    <xs:element name="User">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="core:RawDTO">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="UserId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="Password" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="Active" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="Role" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:RoleRef"/>
                        <xs:element name="Organization" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:OrganizationRef"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Using this binding:

```xml
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               version="2.1">

    <bindings xmlns:tns="http://usermanagement" scd="x-schema::tns">
        <!-- Testing simple element match:
        <bindings scd="tns:User">
            <class name="Uzer"/>
        </bindings>
        -->
        <!-- other attempts:
        tns:User/type::0/model::sequence/tns:Role
        tns:User/type::0/tns:Role
        -->
        <bindings scd="tns:User/type::0/content::0/extension::0/model::sequence/tns:Role">
            <property name="roles"/>
        </bindings>
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="com.test.users"/>
        </schemaBindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

The problem is that I can't get that expression to match and the SCD examples that I found are very little and don't match this type of structure with a *element / complexType / complexContent / extension / sequence*.

The [guide](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-ref/#section-path-examples) I've tried to use as inspiration only has *element / complexType / sequence*: `/schemaElement::my:chapter/type::0`

As far as I saw, the XSOM compiler used by JAXB doesn't like all the expression types from the guide, like `/type::my:articleType/model::sequence/schemaElement::my:appendix`

Any clue on how to match it using SCD?

Thank you

Comment: SCD is tricky. Why not use XPath?

Comment: Because the theory says that SCD is better, so I want to follow that.
I've managed to do it with XPath in the meantime.

Comment: Theory, yes. In the praxis no-one knows SCD. I also almost never needed it, I only had one case where the XPath didn't work and SCD did.
But sorry, I can't help here.

Comment: I have never been able to get scd bindings to match even the most trivial element paths with either shorthand or explicit descriptions.